# Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop CentrifyDC problems

Tags: active-directory

I have a problem with Ubuntu 12.04 when I trying to integrate with Active Directory.

I installed CentrifyDC and i joind the DC. Everything is ok until I reboot my computer and when I try to login with username and domain password I can't do it.Then I log in with my default ubuntu username and if i try command adinfo appears centrifydc in diconnectd mode.
After 3 minutes without any interventions when I type adinfo command centryfidc appears connected and I can login with my domain user and pass.

Same thing is if I execute command: /etc/init.d/centrifydc restart it appear connected.

Can anyone tell me why it can't connect at the boot ? Error when I type: adinfo --diag is: Cannot find SPNs: unable to bind to DC.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, problem resolved by making a script in /etc/network/if-up.d/

```
sudo vim /etc/network/if-up.d/centrify
```

with content:

```
    #!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = lo ]; then
        exit 0 
fi

/etc/init.d/centrifydc restart
initctl emit centrify-connected
```

after I typed:

```
sudo chown root /etc/network/if-up.d/centrify
sudo chgrp root /etc/network/if-up.d/centrify
sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/centrify
```

And then I modified /etc/init/lightdm.conf with right permissions (chown root, chgrp root, chmod 644), and I added only one boot condition.

```
sudo chown root /etc/init/lightdm.conf 
sudo chgrp root /etc/init/lightdm.conf 
sudo chmod 644 /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

then

```
sudo vim /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

and I added only one boot condition.

```
# LightDM - light Display Manager
#
# The display manager service manages the X servers running on the
# system, providing login and auto-login services
#
# based on gdm upstart script

description "LightDM Display Manager"
author      "Robert Ancell <robert.ancell@canonical.com>"

start on ((filesystem
           and runlevel [!06]
           and started dbus
           and (drm-device-added card0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
                or stopped udev-fallback-graphics)
           **and centrify-connected)**
          or runlevel PREVLEVEL=S)

stop on runlevel [016]

emits login-session-start
emits desktop-session-start
emits desktop-shutdown

script
    if [ -n "$UPSTART_EVENTS" ]
    then
        # Check kernel command-line for inhibitors, unless we are being called
        # manually
        for ARG in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do
            if [ "$ARG" = "text" ]; then
        plymouth quit || : 
                stop
        exit 0
            fi
        done

    [ ! -f /etc/X11/default-display-manager -o "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/bin/lightdm" -o "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm" ] || { stop; exit 0; }

    if [ "$RUNLEVEL" = S -o "$RUNLEVEL" = 1 ]
    then
        # Single-user mode
        plymouth quit || :
        exit 0
    fi
    fi

    exec lightdm
end script

post-stop script
    if [ "$UPSTART_STOP_EVENTS" = runlevel ]; then
        initctl emit desktop-shutdown
    fi
end script
```

Be very careful when you do this !